# Leveraging cookie-based authentication in Chromecast Receiver

Tags: chromecast

I've had success with passing access tokens to a receiver from a sender when access to a particular media resource depends on some sort of authorization that the token can provide.

But now I've run into a situation with a particular app where access to the media is controlled not via a token but via a cookie that gets set when a user logs into the site (and it's a cookie that isn't transferable). Is there a way to, in the sender/receiver communications, allow the Chromecast browser to "log into" the site so that it can get the necessary cookies to be able to access the media stream? So for, example, once the casting session is created, have the sender app prompt for login credentials that get passed to the receiver, who then uses it to perform authentication on that side of things?

Or is this too big of a security risk to be thinking about (passing credentials over the sender/receiver channel, that is)?

Comment: Could you briefly describe the general overview as to how you passed the access token to the receiver from a sender, and how you resolved that token on the receiver end so the media could successfully play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between the sender and receiver is over a secure channel but what you are asking  is not going to be a feasible solution. For example, Chrome browser on chromecast no longer saves cookies so they will be gone each time your application stops. You might be better off looking into an alternative approach for accessing that service.

Comment: Is this still the case? It seems weird that still in the year 2020 chromecast sender/receiver cannot handle cookies... What is a common way of doing this?